# SQLAlchemy altering relationship

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Good day, 
I have set of tables from which some tables have many to one relationship. For instance:

```
class Industry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'industry'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('industry_id_seq'), nullable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    companies = relationship('Company',backref=backref('industry',cascade='delete,all'))

class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'company'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('company_id_seq'), nullable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    industry_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Industry.id), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

As you can see several companies can belong to the same industry. Does anybody know what the procedure should be to remove the company object where the industry is being shared among several companies?  Obviously, I wouldn't touch the industry object while the other company objects are present.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Do you mean that you want to remove an industry and all its child companies, starting with the companies?

Comment: Still unclear. Do you simply mean "remove a company"? That's just [`session.delete(company_instance)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.delete), which marks the instance deleted, and the actual deletion will happen during next flush, or you can issue bulk deletes with [Query.delete](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete). Though I'm fairly certain you're after something a little more involved, the question is hard to decipher.

Comment: I want to remove the company, but, because I have many to one relationship at the industry level, it seems to tail to decouple company from the industry and safely delete first. I was trying to set the pointer of the industry to Null and then delete the company, but that didn't work either.

Comment: It comes back with the integrity exception:  IntegrityError: (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tmp`.`company`, CONSTRAINT `company_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`industry_id`) REFERENCES `industry` (`id`))') [SQL: u'UPDATE company SET industry_id=%s WHERE company.id = %s'] [parameters: (None, 1L)]

Answer (score 1):

Each Company object keeps an Industry id as defined foreign key. If you delete a Company it won't be problem because Industry Id is just a reference but if you delete an Industry object which companies use the id of it then will cause a problem. Companies instance can't be exist without a industry:

```
companies = session.query(Company).filter(industry.name=='Tech').all()
#can delete all companies of same industry
first_comp = session.query(Company).filter(industry.name=='Tech').first()
session.delete(first_comp)
session.commit()
```

Comment: Nope, still throws an exception. Perhaps the model is off? IntegrityError: (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tmp`.`company`, CONSTRAINT `company_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`industry_id`) REFERENCES `industry` (`id`))') [SQL: u'UPDATE company SET industry_id=%s WHERE company.id = %s'] [parameters: (None, 2L)]

Comment: Why you are updating `industry_id`? If you going to update industry_id then it must be a valid foreign key, from your Industry table. Otherwise you have to change `nullable=True` for industry_id column in Company table.